# Do custom action after devise model confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I know once the user has confirmed a `Confirmable` account in devise, I can change the redirect URL with:

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource)
  view_context.admin_dashboard_url_for(subdomain: resource.tenant.subdomain)
end
```

But if I wanted to call a custom method on the `resource` after confirmation, how would I do that with devise? I suppose I could stick it in this method...

```
 def after_confirmation_path_for(resource)
   resource.do_thing_after_confirmation
   view_context.admin_dashboard_url_for(subdomain: resource.tenant.subdomain)
 end
```

But that doesn't feel right to have this method changing the model.

Comment: override confirmations controller with your own, define same method, do your action and then call `super()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a [blank method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L252) in `Devise::Models::Confirmable` that is called during the `confirm!` method. I'm going to override this method in my User resource model and do my work here.

```
def after_confirmation
end
```